# How to discover a javascript file on a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Well guys, I want to ask your help to find a javascript file, well I have this script that adds a product to the cart, however, when he opens the page, he can't select the size and click the button to add to cart, because  I unloaded all files that contain `.js` extension, and it is not possible to click on the product size and add to cart without the `.js` file but I unloaded all javascript files, and without this file  javascript, the label to select the size of the shoe and the button to add to cart is not visible or accessible, that is, without this javascript file the option to select the size of the shoe and the button to add to cart does not appear, so I need  find out which file is this, does anyone know how i can do this?  I've already opened the page and opened devtools and used the search function and looked for the term `carrinho` since it has something to do with it, but I couldn't find it, I want to disable all javascript files and load only the one I need, just like I did with css, I disabled all css and only loaded a specific file, as you can see in the code below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');         
const fs = require('fs').promises;                                                                                                              
(async () => {
 try{                                              
  console.log("Started!")                        
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({         
   executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',            
   //headless:false,                               
   args:['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']       
  });                                             
  const page = await browser.newPage();       
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);        
  const blockedResourceTypes = ["image", "bacon", "imageset", "stylesheet", "font", "texttrack", "csp_report", "media", "object", "sub_frame", "main_frame"]                                      
  const allowURLs = ["https://images.lojanike.com.br/site/ni/dist/css/Index.css?v=5b95e1dc7eff61bf78f523058eb924e6",]                                               
  const allowedRequest = req => !blockedResourceTypes.includes(req.resourceType()) && !req.url().endsWith(".js") || allowURLs.includes(req.url())
  page.on('request', (req) => {                   
   if (allowedRequest(req)) {
    req.continue();
   }
   else {                                           
    req.abort();                                   
   }
 });
 const cookiesString = await fs.readFile('./cookies.json');                                      
 const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);      
 await page.setCookie(...cookies);               
 await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-1-x-clot-infantil-24-33-67-80-445-308385', {
  waitUntil: 'load', timeout:0});                   
 const tamanho = await page.$x('//label[@for="tamanho__id32"]', {visible:true})                  
 await tamanho[0].click('//label[@for="tamanho__id32"]');                                        
 const button = await page.waitForSelector("button#btn-comprar", {visible:true})                 
 page.click('button#btn-comprar')                
 console.log("Add to car!")         
}                                                
catch(err){                                      
 console.log(err)
}           
})();
```

Does anyone know how I can find out which javascript file displays the add to cart button?  I just need to load a javascript file but it's hard to find out which file is this, if anyone can help me I'm very grateful, I need to find this file to finish my project.

Comment: Can you clarify "_I unloaded all javascript files_"?

Comment: @Teemu Oh ok, sorry, I'm translating using google translator and sometimes the translation isn't clear, but anyway, I blocked the loading of all javascript files, and I need to find the javascript file that displays the add to cart button and load this javascript file  without loading all javascript files

Comment: why did you unload all javascript files? Surely it's simpler to keep them, and so I assume the reason for unloading them is relevant to the question

Comment: @Fred Stark I blocked it to make my script a little faster